# Error:On installing Visual Studio 2010.ULTIMATE.RTM.X86 on-WinXP-SP3

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2010.ULTIMATE.RTM.X86 on-WinXP-SP3.It is giving errors during installation and exiting.

**Error**:  "There were errors during setup. Although some components were installed successfully, errors were detected."

Error was ac-curing during while installing "Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 Update(x86)"